# graphics card for AMD Ryzen 3 3200G

Tags: graphics-cards

My son built himself a computer back in 2019 with an AMD Ryzen 3 3200G Processor and an ASUS Prime B450M-A Micro ATX Motherboard. He’s finding it’s not up to handling the graphics on the games he wants to play (e.g. Subnautica). Any suggestions for upgrades/graphics cards?

Comment: Since he is now gaming with the igpu, can I assume he games at 1080p?

Comment: His display is 1920 x 1080

Comment: I've used a 3200G in the past and had it paired up with a GTX 970, which complemented nicely without much bottlenecking. Anything along the lines of a 970, 1060 or RX-570 would be a good match.

Comment: I like the RX 570 idea, I also have one